# Need MVC3 Razor Grid that loads by JSON/AJAX and has frozen columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, grid, getjson, telerik-grid

I need a grid on an MVC3 Razor page that will have to load by JSON or AJAX call. I need this grid to be editable as well.

Also I need the grid to have the ability to have the first 6-8 columns frozen. I looked at the example on Codeproject.com and I couldnt get it to work. My scrollbars would show up but couldnt get the columns to freeze.

I have been working on this using Telerik grids, but it doesnt have the ability to freeze columns by default in a razor setting.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this or where I could look for some more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try jQuery EasyUI http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php

I did initially suggest jqGrid: http://www.trirand.com/blog/
but apparently it's a faff to get frozen columns using it.

Comment: Thanks BonyT that is what I needed. I dont have enough reputation to give an up vote for you yet, sorry about that.